# Change from Public Function to Sub

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup, lookup

I have been using the below code to run a vlookup-style search and return all matches (whilst omitting duplicates and blanks). I want to convert this into a VBA macro that I can call using a button to, by row, search for the value in column C in column A, and return each corresponding value from column B. I want these results printed in column D, separated by a ";". Does anyone know a good way to do this? I've also attached an example image of my goal output.

Thanks!

```
Public Function Vlookup2(ByVal Lookup_Value As String, ByVal Cell_Range As 
Range, ByVal Column_Index As Integer) As Variant
Dim cell As Range
Dim Result_String As String

On Error GoTo eHandle

For Each cell In Cell_Range

If cell.Value = Lookup_Value Then
    If cell.Offset(0, Column_Index - 1).Value <> "" Then
        If Not Result_String Like "*" & cell.Offset(0, Column_Index - 1).Value & "*" Then
            Result_String = Result_String & ";!;" & cell.Offset(0, Column_Index - 1).Value
        End If
    End If
End If

Next cell

Vlookup2 = LTrim(Right(Result_String, Len(Result_String) - 1))

Exit Function

eHandle:
Vlookup2 = ""

End Function
```

[image]

Comment: you will want to find the last cell in C that has a value then loop from C2 to that, and then run the function on each value in C and put the result is D.  Please show what you tried to do that does that.

Comment: Hi Scott, thanks for responding. I honestly have no idea where to start with making this a Sub instead of a function as I'm not sure how to define the variables whilst also looping?

Comment: You would not make that a sub, you would call that from a sub that loops the data.  What you are asking for is for us to code this for you.  That is not what this site is for.  You need to show your attempt to do what you want and explain where you are stuck.  This is too broad for this site.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach you could try:

```vb
Sub SummarizeAddresses()
    
    Dim dict As Object, c As Range, ws As Worksheet
    Dim pc As String, addr As String, k
    
    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    Set ws = ActiveSheet 'or whatever
    
    'loop over the input data
    For Each c In ws.Range("A2:A" & ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Cells
        pc = Trim(c.Value)
        addr = c.Offset(0, 1).Value
        If Not dict.exists(pc) Then Set dict(pc) = New Collection 'new code?
        On Error Resume Next  'ignore error if adding a duplicate
        dict(pc).Add addr, addr
        On Error GoTo 0       'stop ignoring errors
    Next c
    
    Set c = ws.Range("C2")  'starting point for output
    For Each k In dict
        c.Value = k
        c.Offset(0, 1).Value = CollectionItems(dict(k))
        Set c = c.Offset(1, 0) 'next row down
    Next k
End Sub

'return a string with all elements of a collection
Function CollectionItems(col As Collection)
    Dim rv As String, e, sep As String
    For Each e In col
        rv = rv & sep & e
        sep = ";"
    Next e
    CollectionItems = rv
End Function
```